# Why is my array modeling a deck of cards returning null card objects?

Tags: java, arrays, null

so this is my deck class populating a deck of cards

```java
/**
Constructs a deck with 52 cards
*/
public Deck() {

    int k = 0;  // counter to keep track of elements in the deck array

    // nested for loops to populate the deck of cards with 4 suits and 13 possible rankings
    for (int i = 1; i < SUITS; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < RANKS; j++) {
            deckOfCards[k] = new Card(i, j);  // adds the cards to the deck array 
            k++;                              // increment the elements counter by 1
            System.out.println(deckOfCards[k]);
        }
    }

}
```

this is my card class even though I'm almost positive there isn't anything wrong with this part

```java
public class Card {

    private int rank;
    private int suit;

    /**
    * @param suit the suit of the card in a deck 
    * @param rank the rank of the card in a deck 
    */
    public Card(int suit, int rank) {

        this.rank = rank;       // initializing the rank 
        this.suit = suit;       // initializing the suit
    }
```

When I print out the cards in the deck, I get `null` returned. Any ideas why?

Comment: So your saying that `System.out.println(deckOfCards[k]);` prints `null`? Once? many times? How often? Or do you mean that you get a `NullPointerException`? That are different things. Please be very precise when asking questions. It would help if you copy paste your full output and also confirm which part in your code prints the stuff you see.

Comment: You're incrementing `k` _before_ printing `deckOfCards[k]`.  Which means that you're getting the _next_ entry in `deckOfCards`, and not the one you just added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```java
deckOfCards[k] = new Card(i, j);
k++;
System.out.println(deckOfCards[k]);
```

You're setting `deckOfCards[k]` but printing `deckOfCards[k+1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you already initialized deckOfCards, so your problem is that your incrementing k before printing the card.
If you remove k++ and change println(deckOfCards[k]) to println(deckOfCards[k++]) it should do the trick because it uses k and then increments it.

P.S: sorry for no code format, I'm doing this on my phone